# Building a theme identification system with OpenAI: facing challenges

Tags: openai-api

I'm trying to build a system that, based on a provided query, identifies the theme or themes of the query by choosing from predefined themes. As output, I need a structured response like 'Theme': ['Theme1, Theme4,..'].

and what I want to achieve, with some examples. Unfortunately, despite specifying the format of my response, it always remains somewhat casual (e.g., Response: 'Theme':[..], or Here's the response: 'Theme ': [...]) which makes it challenging to follow instructions (I'd like to avoid writing regex).

I tried using OpenAI's function calling. I defined a function that transforms a string into JSON and takes a string as input. The function description and LLM call are as follows:

```
#Themes list

themes_vect = '[Theme1, Theme2, ...]'
Function description

function_description = [{
  'name': 'to_json',
  'description': 'Converts a strings into JSON',
  'parameters': {
    'type': 'object',
    'properties': {
      'theme': {
        'type': 'string',
        'list': themes_vect,
        'description': 'Theme/themes of the query, e.g., [\'Theme1\', \'Theme2\']'
      }
    },
    'required': ['theme']
  }
}]
#Openai call

sys_message = "Your task is to analyze a query and identify the theme, choosing from a        predefined list of themes."

query = "talk me about theme1 and theme2"

prompt = "query: {}".format(query)

resp = opneai.ChatCompletion.create( model = "gpt3-turbo",
messages = [{"role": "system", "content": sys_message},
         {"role": "user", "content":prompt}],
functions_description = function_description,
function_call = "auto")`
```

Certainly, the output is structured, but I noticed that it struggles to identify more than one theme in a query (even if is very clear). What am i doing wrong?

Could this problem be solved by changing or adding some key-value pairs in the parameter properties? I admit that I added 'list': 'themes_list' without fully understanding what it does exactly. Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried a few-shot prompting approach here? Include some examples in your prompt with the desired output. If it is failing to detect more than 1 theme, include such an example as well.